# Error when using @JsonDeserialize with @JsonCreator

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I have a class which I'm trying to deserialise some JSON into. One of the properties has a custom converter attached via the @JsonDeserialize annotation. The deserialisation works fine when the class is written with setters and the annotations on the setters like this:

```
public class Rates extends AbstractResponse {

    private Date effectiveDate;
    private List<Rate> rates;

    public Rates(Date effectiveDate, List<Rate> rates) {
        this.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
        this.rates = rates;
    }

    public Date getEffectiveDate() {
        return this.effectiveDate;
    }

    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    public void setEffectiveDate(Date effectiveDate) {
        this.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
    }

    @JsonDeserialize(converter = RatesTableConverter.class)
    public void setRates(List<Rate> rates) {
        this.rates = rates;
    }

    public List<Rate> getRates() {
        return this.rates;
    }
```

}

But when I re-write it to be like this:

```
public class Rates extends AbstractResponse {

    private final Date effectiveDate;
    private final List<Rate> rates;

    @JsonCreator
    public Rates(
            @JsonProperty("timestamp") Date effectiveDate,
            @JsonProperty("rates") 
            @JsonDeserialize(converter = RatesTableConverter.class) List<Rate> rates) {
        this.effectiveDate = effectiveDate;
        this.rates = rates;
    }

    public Date getEffectiveDate() {
        return this.effectiveDate;
    }

    public List<Rate> getRates() {
        return this.rates;
    }

}
```

I get this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
```

I've messed around with a number of ideas and cannot get it to work. It appears that when used on a constructor, that the deserialiser is not being checked correctly.

Any ideas what I've missed?

Comment: Interesting problem! I tried to recreate it but got a different error. However, when I used a `JsonDeserializer<List<Rate>>` and the annotation `@JsonDeserialize(using = RateDeserializer.class)` instead I got it to work.